# Excel - Get Unique values in Column in between dates in another column

Tags: excel, date, count, unique

I have been trying to get this for a couple of days now. I have read several articles on similiar achievements but have been unable to get any of them to work.

Column A has a list of names that represent a person attending that work day; column I represent the date for that work day.

I need to look through a date range for one week in "I" and get the unique count of names that were present in "A".

I can get the count but I cant get th unique count using

```
=COUNTIFS('DIRECT TIME'!I:I,">="&B25,'DIRECT TIME'!I:I,"<="&C25)
```

Can someone help me figure this out. I have tried to implement functions i have found online using frequency and sumproduct/count but have been unable to get any of them to work.

Thanks,

-Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically you can use a formula like this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Dates>=A1,IF(Dates<=A2,IF(Names<>"",MATCH(Names,Names,0)))),ROW(Names)-MIN(ROW(Names))+1),1))`

Confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Names and Dates should be the same size and as small as possible because the formula can be slow